# Calculate CV2 Homography by points and line

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

I have a list of points in the field (like `upper_goal_point`/ `left_upper_outer_corner`, etc.

[image]

I know their corresponding coordinates in destination image - so I can calculate the homography:

```
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
```

I also have blue points in the upper corner line (look at image above), **which I only know that their destination's `y` coordinates are 0** (because they are in the upper line), but I don't know where exactly they lay in that line.

Can I use those blue points in order to improve the homography?

P.S.

You can see that the `upper corner` line in the homography is not horizontal line, it's diagonal, which of course is not correct:

[image]

Comment: To my understanding there is no way to use a line during the standard way of homography estimation, since you need point correspondences. But you can use the line for testing the quality of your homography. If you know the real length of a line segment, you can however generate points along that line.

Comment: @Micka I am actually using it for testing (: but there is alot of frames with low score, so I thought maybe its possible use this knowledge in the calculation of homography. I also thought of creating artificial points in the outer_corner line (e.g. calculating the intersection between the outer_corner line and upper_corner line, and its about 16.5 meters from left_upper_corner point)

Comment: Stop using `cv2.findHomography`, (find out what process Homograpy is estimated by if necessary,) and implement an estimation process that uses your constraints.

Comment: the intersection was the first thing that came to my mind, too. Willl work if the box lines are straight and distances are correct AND lens distortion is low. Looks ok in those images

Comment: The way of @fana would work, if you are strong in math and programming. You can "easily" use the known direction as one of the inputs to solve the necessary equations. E.g. 3 points and 1 direction should work, or 2 points and 2 directions, etc.

Comment: Homography estimation is pose estimation (between two viewpoints).
The line constraint is weaker than the point constraint, but I think adding it to the pose estimation will have a corresponding effect.

Comment: @Micka I'm not computer vision expert, just ambitious DevOps guy  ):

Comment: @fana I think you are right. I missed that direction (normalized vector) is just a single degree of freedom (basically an angle) so instead of 1 point correspondence you would need 2 independent direction correspondences.

Comment: Or... Treating the x-coordinate vlaues of the blue points as estimation target too, may be one way?
They (x-coordinate) may be able to be updated based on the evaluation of `cv2.findHomography` result.
So, it may be possible to construct an iterative method ( findHomography -> update x -> findHomography -> update x ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it possible to use line correspondence in find homography.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220845575_Combining_Line_and_Point_Correspondences_for_Homography_Estimation

Several years ago we implement this approach in one project. During simplification all math we come up with simple trick. We transform every line `a*x + b*y + c = 0` to point `(a/c, b/c)`

```cpp
// ***  Don't copy paste this code, read below!  ***//
Point2f convertPointsToHomogeneousLine(Point2f p1, Point2f p2) {
    Point3f p1h(p1.x, p1.y, 1);
    Point3f p2h(p2.x, p2.y, 1);
    Point3f lineHomo(p1h.y*p2h.z - p1h.z*p2h.y,
                     p1h.z*p2h.x - p1h.x*p2h.z,
                     p1h.x*p2h.y - p1h.y*p2h.x);
    
    Point2f lineHomoNorm(lineHomo.x / lineHomo.z,
                         lineHomo.y / lineHomo.z);
    return lineHomoNorm;
}
```

And pass this points inside. As I remember I also dig inside OpenCV implementation of `findHomography` and insert this lines somewhere inside to solve step. Inside OpenCV there some normalization applied to points before pass to solve step. So you need to skip this step for this kind of points.

We do not use it in production. User need to calibrate camera manually by providing lines and points on the image and in meter system. It has too complicated interface and bad stability. But in your case I think it can work better. If you will automatically find lines and correspondence.

> P.S. Please note that in paper they use some normalization technique.
> It will improve stability. We faced with stability problem, do not
> solved it in our journey.